# English Stack Exchange swag for top users

Tags: discussion, swag

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- English Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- English Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: english.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: english.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Cool! Together with my Google Summer of Code mentor T-shirt, this will definitely increase my geek value!

Comment: I had no idea I was still on the second page. Thanks much!

Comment: STACK EXCHANGE: No, YOU GUYS rock!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks very much - slightly ironic as a 32K+beta user on SO, a physicist and professional programmer I get an Eng Lit T-shirt!

Comment: Congratulations to all our top users! Your contributions are very much appreciated, and I am delighted that The Powers That Be are showing their appreciation with this generous gift.

Comment: @Jasper all the graduated SE sites' top users will be getting this package in the near future.

Comment: I just clicked the various links, and I have to say: oooh, Uniball Deluxe Fine-point pens... yummmm... drooool...

Comment: Wow! Thanks Jeff & co! (And I didn't know what a sharpie was either.)

Comment: Me so happy! :D

Comment: @Jasper Loy: *[Whispering]* Shhhh! Don't let the cat out of the bag. You're supposed to be an expert in English! ^_^

Comment: **Love it!** (well, so far, just the idea, but I just know I'll love the actual goodiebag when it arrives, and I have complete faith in my main man Jeff that it *will*!) Seriously, I really do think EL&U is a good thing both to exist, and to be part of. I'm gonna enjoy (un)baring my chest and announcing my allegiance to the world at large. Definitely one up on your average rock concert tee-shirt, thanks Jeff!

Comment: oh man, i just made page 21

Comment: Wow, cool idea.  I'm guessing I missed, alas -- I'm there *now*, but I have no idea if I was a week ago. :-(

Comment: OK, dunno whether I'm being impatient, but I still haven't received my swag package :(:) I responded to the email as soon as I got it and I live in NJ. Hope it arrives soon!

Comment: @Jimi Oke I didn't respond right away but here as well: nothing...

Comment: @jimi still working on it! expect 6-8 weeks, hopefully sooner.

Comment: @jeff: thanks for info. don't worry, when it comes to waiting, i'm a true vulture!

Comment: @Jeff: It is highly possible that I will have moved by the time this ships. Is there any convenient way for me to update my address? My future address can already receive my mail.

Comment: @mrhen sure just email team@stackexchange.com with your new info

Comment: Snif, page 3 :(

Comment: Package arrived today. Thanks StackExchange people!

Comment: @JeffAtwood: FWIW, I never got this package. :(

Comment: Note to later readers: [The shop is closed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store)

Answer (score 4):

That e-mail was as appreciated as unexpected.

I was wondering, though, about something. It's just to be sure, but in the e-mail you say "*no matter where in the world you live*", does that mean that also the shipping is free?

And the package will include one item of each category? Thanks again! :)

Comment: yes it is completely free and contains each item listed in the question.

Comment: @Jeff sorry to bother again, but I forgot to specify that I'm out of the U.S., exactly in Europe... Thanks again! :D

Comment: @alen as it says in the email and form, "Just fill out the below form and we'll get it mailed out to you ASAP. (International mailing addresses are OK!)"

Comment: I think what @Alenanno is trying to say is that he's not really in this world. Europe isn't a real place, is it?

Comment: @Alenanno: I'm sure Jeff isn't one of those (lamentably not non-existent) Americans who think that Italy/Europe/Britain/England are all "more or less" the same place. We *do* exist seperately and collectively; without Latin we'd have no English; and without English we'd have no EL&U. Have faith!

Comment: Ahah It's not a crime to want to be sure, is it? :D

Answer (score 3):

Kewl! One question, though: what exactly do you mean by "your Programmers Stack Exchange account name"? I.e. for me, is that "Martha" or "1547" or something else?

Edit: ok, so I started typing "Martha", and it filled the field with "http://english.stackexchange.com/users/1547/martha". I take it that the field should be filled out with a link to your user profile? (In that case, shouldn't the field be a *leeetle* bit wider? And better labeled?)

Edit 7/8/2011: I still haven't received my swag. Should I be worried?

Comment: I had the exact same issue.  And the fact that it said "Programmers Stack Exchange" threw me a bit as well =D

Comment: @dusty I changed it to say "your account name on the site"

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - Danke.  And I should say, for both the change and the swag.

Comment: Interestingly, mine did not auto-complete my profile link (Tried in Chrome and IE9) Have others had it happen one way or another?

Comment: @Dusty: Me as well, although I guess it shouldn't be a problem... :D

Comment: By the way, I wrote "Alenanno" and that's all... Hope that works :D

Answer (score 2):

Um... I got the e-mail, I swear I did, but some time during the night I seem to have lost ground and am now the top user listed on the *third* page. Obviously I hope to improve this state of affairs as quickly as possible, but I figured I should let you know I'm not trying to scam you guys... really.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome — thank you for a lovely surprise present!  Another question: for shipping within the US, do you use USPS, or a courier (eg UPS/Fedex)?  The place I’m staying at the moment goes by different addresses depending on who’s delivering, for obscure reasons which I don’t understand.

Comment: Now that is weird... :D