# Mis-printed English.se T-shirts

Tags: discussion, swag

We have mailed out the [swag packages](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/english-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) for our top users. Some of you have already received them.

Unfortunately, I made a terrible error. I misspelled the site URL on the T-shirt in the vector file I sent to the printshop. It was spelled "english.stackchange.com" instead of "english.stackexchange.com."

I'm going to print out a new batch of T-shirts and mail the top users again. Printing will take about two weeks. Mailing will take about a bit over a week within the US and a bit longer for non-US residents. I'm estimating the total time will be about 3.5-5 weeks.

I sincerely apologize for this error. I know you all have been waiting patiently for this package.

BTW the stickers are fine.

Comment: I told Jin to tell everyone we did this ironically, an English error just for english.se!

Comment: You "miss-spelled" the site URL? That's not like you. ^_^

Comment: @Robusto I just fail at English that's all. Meanwhile, please enjoy your ultra-rare-collector's-edition of the English.se T-shirt...(once you receive it)

Comment: For me there's nothing to apologize, we will have 2 t-shirts, one being original! :)

Comment: Misspelled domain names don't count as English errors. `:-)`

Comment: 3.5-5 weeks?  [6-8 WEEKS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) AROUND HERE, BUDDY!

Comment: :-O You don't have to apologize to *us* that the first scoop of the free ice-cream you're giving was the wrong flavor.  And maybe someday, each of these shirts will be the equivalent of an [Inverted Jenny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_Jenny).

Comment: I like it in any colour or spelling!

Comment: The real question is, who's going to to snatch up the _english.stackchange_ domain, and what are they going to do with it?

Comment: I feel I should maybe return my T-shirt, but not because it's a defective product. I'm just not sure I deserve it, considering if I hadn't chanced upon this page, I'd probably never have even noticed.

Comment: @Jin Did you get the notification of my answer here? :D

Comment: Just buy the domain stackchange.com. It's too late now to go back. lol

Answer (score 18):

No no no no. You're going about this all wrong. What you *should* have said was, these are do-it-yourself shirts: using the English knowledge gained from this site, you have to use the Sharpie to make the appropriate corrections to the shirt. The letter enclosed with the package serves as the example.

Comment: Except that *StackExchange* is not quite an English word!

Comment: @Jimi: oh, hush. Quit bothering me with details. Hmph.

Comment: Haha! True, it would've been neat to have the same theme of correction for the t-shirt, but publicity/marketing would've definitely suffered. Not good for business!

Comment: +1: *There's* the old school-teacher spirit. If you can't get 'em with a ruler, get 'em with a Sharpie™!

Answer (score 1):

WHOA! I got the package and everything is COOL. Thank you so much, I don't care about the misspelling at all! :D

I was wondering: would it be perhaps possible to maybe change the size? My t-shirt is a little big (damn you, different country sizes eheh... My fault, I know) so I was wondering if I could choose a smaller size for the next one.

It's not an actual problem, I mean, I can still use the t-shirt. But I wanted to wear it and go out, looking like a real geek, but now it's too big for me.

Comment: I have updated the spreadsheet. Made your size one size smaller.

Comment: @Jin Thanks a lot! Is there a place where I can look at the corresponding sizes between Italy/US or Europe/US? **Sorry** if I'm bothering you, I just want to be sure of it before you print it. (The current one was really big :D)

Comment: I googled and found this: http://www.meixsell.com/EbayInfo/WWconversion.html

Comment: @Jin Sorry for answering late, I had something urgent to do... Anyway, I measured and I'm around 95-97 cm (more or less 37 inches)... so that means a M size? Thanks a lot!!! :)

Comment: yep. already changed your size to a M lastnight

Comment: @Jin Thanks again and sorry for troubling you! :)

Comment: no trouble at all!